# Why would Get-Service not find the service with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I am having problems with a powershell script.

I wrote a script that would search for a windows service with a specific name, and it would Stop or Start this service.

It works when I run it on a server which I log into with a service account that I know that can access the service console.  However when it runs off of my build server, the script is no longer able to find the services.  I tried giving the service account that runs script the same privaledges as the other service account but that doesn't seem to work.

```
[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController]$service = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ComputerName $Remoteserver -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

That is the line that is not longer able to find the service.  What am I doing wrong.  Is there a way to impersonate a user that can find the service? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a basic permissions issue, does the account running the get-service command on the build server have access to get the service account? does a manual execution work when you run it with a domain account that has admin rights on the remote system ? To impersonate a user, you can open a new cmd window with runas as the domain service account.

Comment: You could go back and accept some answers on your old questions.

Comment: I had the same problem using our build server to stop a service remotely. When I added the serviceaccount that was used to execute the tasks of the build server to the local admin group of the server where my service was hosted, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try supplying the credentials of the service account using the **-Credential** parameter. However, since you imply that it *used to* work with the account that runs the script remotely and no longer does, I think a more likely culprit is that **$ServiceName** used to only match one service on the target computer, and now there is another service whose name matches that string. If more than one service matches the **-Name** parameter, **Get-Service** returns an *array* of ServiceController objects.

Try running it without `ErrorAction -SilentlyContinue`. If you get the following error message, then that's what's happening:

> Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController".

If you get a different error message, please add the full error message to the question.